# How to set Textview at the bottom of my screen in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Explanation: I have a screen where i want to put my textview at the bottom of my screen. I have scrollview in which i want to put my textview at the bottom.

here is my land/activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.millu.multiplescreendemo.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/land_login_img_height"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_desc"
        android:background="@drawable/login_bg"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/subLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/img_login"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_desc">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/label_signin"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:gravity="center"-->
                <!--android:textColor="@color/signin_color"-->
                <!--android:text="@string/label_signin"/>-->
                <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:gravity="center"-->
                <!--android:text="@string/label_msg"-->
                <!--android:textSize="@dimen/welcome_label"-->
                <!--android:textColor="@color/msg_color"/>-->

                <!--<EditText-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/txt_username"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_username"-->
                <!--android:drawablePadding="5dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"-->
                <!--android:textSize="@dimen/username_hint_size"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginRight="8dp"-->
                <!--android:textColorHint="@color/hint_text_color"-->
                <!--android:hint="@string/hint_user"/>-->

                <!--<EditText-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/txt_password"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_password"-->
                <!--android:drawablePadding="5dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginRight="8dp"-->
                <!--android:textSize="@dimen/password_hint_size"-->
                <!--android:textColorHint="@color/hint_text_color"-->
                <!--android:hint="@string/hint_pass"/>-->
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/btn_text_color"
                    android:background="@color/btn_bg_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/btn_signin"
                    android:text="@string/bnt_text"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/forgot_text_size"
                    android:text="@string/label_forgot"
                    android:textColor="@color/forgot_text_color"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_signup_forgot_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_sign_up_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/acc_signup_title"
                    android:textColor="@color/acc_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/label_have_acc" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_sign_up"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt_sign_up_title"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt_sign_up_title"
                    android:text="@string/txt_signup_link"
                    android:textColor="@color/txt_signup_link"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/forgot_text_size" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Check above code in landscape view.

Help me, to solve out this problem.

Comment: put your textview outside of scrollview and alignParentBottom=true in textview

Answer (score 1):

Just put this outside the scrollview...

```
     <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center">
 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_sign_up_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/acc_signup_title"
                    android:textColor="@color/acc_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/label_have_acc" />
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_sign_up"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt_sign_up_title"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt_sign_up_title"
                    android:text="@string/txt_signup_link"
                    android:textColor="@color/txt_signup_link"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/forgot_text_size" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

And in Scrollview add the following line..

```
android:layout_above="@id/footer"
```

Comment: but i want to scroll that textview

Comment: if you want to scroll and also wanna place your textview at bottom not possible.....just scroll all the views except that textview which you want to place in the bottom...both means are same

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below,

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/bottomArea"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:background="#B5B5B5"
   android:paddingTop="10dp"
   android:paddingBottom="10dp"
>
/**this linear layout is position to bottom.
* Add your button here...
*/
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.millu.multiplescreendemo.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/land_login_img_height"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_desc"
        android:background="@drawable/login_bg"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/subLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/img_login"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_desc">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/label_signin"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:gravity="center"-->
                <!--android:textColor="@color/signin_color"-->
                <!--android:text="@string/label_signin"/>-->
                <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:gravity="center"-->
                <!--android:text="@string/label_msg"-->
                <!--android:textSize="@dimen/welcome_label"-->
                <!--android:textColor="@color/msg_color"/>-->

                <!--<EditText-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/txt_username"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_username"-->
                <!--android:drawablePadding="5dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"-->
                <!--android:textSize="@dimen/username_hint_size"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginRight="8dp"-->
                <!--android:textColorHint="@color/hint_text_color"-->
                <!--android:hint="@string/hint_user"/>-->

                <!--<EditText-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/txt_password"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_password"-->
                <!--android:drawablePadding="5dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginRight="8dp"-->
                <!--android:textSize="@dimen/password_hint_size"-->
                <!--android:textColorHint="@color/hint_text_color"-->
                <!--android:hint="@string/hint_pass"/>-->
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/btn_text_color"
                    android:background="@color/btn_bg_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/btn_signin"
                    android:text="@string/bnt_text"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/forgot_text_size"
                    android:text="@string/label_forgot"
                    android:textColor="@color/forgot_text_color"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_signup_forgot_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_sign_up_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/acc_signup_title"
                    android:textColor="@color/acc_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/label_have_acc" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_sign_up"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt_sign_up_title"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt_sign_up_title"
                    android:text="@string/txt_signup_link"
                    android:textColor="@color/txt_signup_link"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/forgot_text_size" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="bottem text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```